# Google plus sign in, whats the best way to refresh the session?

Tags: google-plus

For a web application that doesn't reload the page with in 3600 seconds, whats the best way to keep the session alive with google plus?

1. If I use the html sign in button, is there a javascript call to refresh the session?
2. Do I need to refresh the token, but does that update the session?
3. Would it be best to call the server and refresh the token, but then I need to update the client cookie?
4. Should I reload the page, this would suck b/c its an application that shouldn't do that?
5. Can I ask the javascript to sign in again, but I get a popup blocker?

How do I deal with the 3600 token expiring in a web application that doesn't refresh the page?

```
<span id="signinButton">
        <span class="g-signin" data-callback="signinCallback" 
            data-clientid="xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin" 
            data-accesstype="offline"
            data-approvalprompt="auto"
            data-theme="dark"
            data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
            data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
            https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
            https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email 
            email">
        </span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`gapi.auth.authorize`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize) call of the JS Client library (which will be loaded with the Sign-in JS script), providing the same parameters you did in the Sign-in Button, and using `'immediate': true`. Since the user already authenticated before, this will refresh the token automatically (if necessary).